# Big O runtime analysis for 3-way recursion with memoization

Tags: algorithm, recursion, runtime, big-o, dynamic-programming

I'm doing some practice interview questions and came across this one:

> Given a list of integers which represent hedge heights, determine the minimum number of moves to make the hedges pretty - that is, compute the minimum number of changes needed to make the array alternate between increasing and decreasing. For example, `[1,6,6,4,4]` should return 2 as you need to change the second 6 to something >6 and the last 4 to something <4. Assume the min height is 1 and the max height is 9. You can change to any number that is between 1 and 9, and that counts as 1 move regardless of the diff to the current number.

My solution is here: https://repl.it/@plusfuture/GrowlingOtherEquipment

I'm trying to figure out the big O runtime for this solution, which is memoized recursion. I think it's `O(n^3)` because for each index, I need to check against 3 possible states for the rest of the array, `changeUp`, `noChange`, and `changeDown`. My friend maintains that it's `O(n)` since I'm memoizing most of the solutions and exiting branches where the array is not "pretty" immediately.

Can someone help me understand how to analyze the runtime for this solution? Thanks.

Comment: All the numbers in array are between 1-9? If yes, because array is strictly increasing or decreasing, the length of array should be no more than 10. Its meanless to discuss the complexity using N. It is a constant complexity.

Comment: You are trying to make it alternating. The array could be given in any configuration. Length could be infinitely long. Each value n in the array is between 1 and 9.